# howto create a table in the output from the content of a file?

Tags: awk

I have a file named `service.yaml` like this:

by using which command (and with which specific options) I can create this table in the output?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print "\"service\" \"version\" \"replica\""
}
/^service/{
  count++
  ser[count]=$0
  next
}
/replica/{
  rep[count]=$NF
  next
}
/version/{
  ver[count]=$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print ser[i],ver[i],rep[i]
  }
}'  Input_file | column -t
```

---

---

In case one wants to run it like `.awk` file then try following.

```
BEGIN{
  print "\"service\" \"version\" \"replica\""
}
/^service/{
  count++
  ser[count]=$0
  next
}
/replica/{
  rep[count]=$NF
  next
}
/version/{
  ver[count]=$NF
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print ser[i],ver[i],rep[i]
  }
}
```

Run command as follows:

```
awk -f codeOP.awk Input_file
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ok, I created file named 'my.awk' contain your code and then at the end of the code instead of 'Input_file' I replaced: 'service.yaml' and at the end I used this command: 'awk -f my.awk service.yaml' but: can't open file 'my.awk'

Comment: Then you didn't  create `my.awk` in the same directory that you're running the command from.

Comment: @EdMorton no I already used cat, grep in bash script in my code and I had all required data in the output, for simplicity I want to change the way to have a table in the output

Comment: @Sherwin, then please use `|`(pipe) after those commands and then run `awk` code, no need to mention Input_file then, since you are getting output from previous command.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes both 'my.awk' and 'service.yaml' are in the same directory

Comment: @Sherwin I didn't say anything about cat, grep, or the input file or the output, I said `you didn't create my.awk in the same directory that you're running the command from`. The only other possibility if you're getting `can't open file 'my.awk'` is that you created a `my.awk` file that you can't read which seems extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'[:[:space:]]+' -v OFS='"\t"' '
    FNR==1 { print "\"" "service", $4, $2 "\"" }
    { print "\"" $1, $5, $3 "\"" }
' service.yaml
"service"       "version"       "replica"
"service-1"     "0.6.24"        "2"
"service-2"     "0.21.14"       "3"
```